# store duplicate list entries together in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of duplicate entries, e.g.

`lista = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]`

How to get the following output:

`output_list = [[1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4],[5]]`

Comment: I reverted revision 2, because you completely changed the question. The existing answers do not make sense anymore if you change the question that much. If you have a different question, please ask a new question. However, do not forget to search for an answer first. This is very basic stuff, and has been asked and answered many times before. So you might risk your new question to be closed as duplicate as well. You might want to read [ask] for some tips.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lista)]
[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [5]]
```

`groupby` returns consecutive groups of identical items as iterables that you can turn into lists with `list()`.